# Deny flash plugin access to (a particular) webcam

Tags: debian, permissions, adobe-flash, camera, chrome

I recently bought an external webcam to play around with OpenCV. It works great out of the box in Debian, but I realized that when I browse any site that contain flash content (youtube, soundcloud), the activity LED on the webcam flashes and in that time other applications (like Cheese) cannot access the webcam.

Naturally I denied webcam access in the flash player context menu and chose the other, built-in, camera for use with the plugin, but the problem still persists.

I think (although I'm not entirely sure) it all started the first time I set flash plugin to use this webcam, I don't think it happened before that. But still purging `flashplayer-nonfree` and reinstalling it doesn't change anything.

Is there a way to keep flash plugin from activating this particular webcam while keeping it available to other applications? Or perhaps there is a way to revert the situation to the state **before** I first touched the flash settings, but **after** I plugged in the camera (assuming my memory serves me right)?

I'm using an updated Debian squeeze and an Microsoft LifeCam Studio webcam. The browser I am talking about is Chrome v. 21.0.1180.57.

**edit:** This only persists while using chrome, when I switched to iceweasel, this wasn't happening. I guess that shows this can be chrome-related.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, it happens because Chrome uses built-in flash plugin.
Built-in plugin located here:

```
/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
```

and it is PPAPI type plug-in ... so it use global Flash Settings, which available at Adobe Flash Settings Manager webpage.

Try to make Chrome using your Mozilla `flashplayer-nonfree` and deactivate built-in Chrome flash-plugin.
After installation Chrome will use both versions, signed above and:

```
/usr/lib/< your_flash_plugin_vendor >/libflashplayer.so
```

so it can looks like:

```
/usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so
```

However, it can bring a bit lower security for Chrome. After installation your Chrome will use both version, and second version have NPAPI type and will be processed in your local system.

Configs available at `chrome:plugins` built-in page.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely some settings got left over in a config file somewhere, despite reinstalling the flash player. `~/.adobe/Flash_Player` is where the settings usually are (as flash uses an external instller/downloader script, at least on my machine, purging may miss this folder), or maybe chrome stores them in your profile somewhere (`~/.config/google-chrome`).